# Pyspark RDD create 2 rows from one row into new Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, lambda, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like:

```
data = [('valorant','web', 'start'),
  ('counter-strike','android', 'start'),
  ('sims','web', 'finished'), 
]

columns = ["game","platform", "type"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = columns)
df.show()
```

```
+--------------+--------+--------+
|          game|platform|    type|
+--------------+--------+--------+
|      valorant|     web|   start|
|counter-strike| android|   start|
|          sims|     web|finished|
+--------------+--------+--------+
```

Which I want to turn into:

```
+--------------+-----+
|          game|count|
+--------------+-----+
|      valorant|    1|
|counter-strike|    1|
|          sims|    1|
|          sims|    1|
+--------------+-----+
```

So that if `type == 'finished'` the new RDD should have 2 rows with value 1 instead of just one row with value 1.
Is there any way I can do this without having to map dataframe 2 times and then merge those RDDs?

If I do:

```
def func1(x):
  if x.type == "start":
    return (x.game, 1)
  elif x.type == "finished":
    return ((x.game, 1), (x.game, 1))

rdd2=df.rdd.map(lambda x: func1(x))
df2=rdd2.toDF(['game',  'value'])
df2.show(truncate=False)
```

```
+---------------------------+-----+
|game                       |value|
+---------------------------+-----+
|valorant                   |1    |
|counter                    |1    |
|[Ljava.lang.Object;@4b01785|null |
+---------------------------+-----+
```

It does not work obviously since func1 expects one value in return. Any ideas?

Comment: count will always be `1`?

Comment: Yes, count will always be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`when` expression + `explode` literal array:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "count",
    F.explode(
        F.when(F.col("type") == "start", F.array(F.lit(1)))
            .when(F.col("type") == "finished", F.array(F.lit(1), F.lit(1)))
    )
).drop("platform", "type")

df1.show()

#+--------------+-----+
#|          game|count|
#+--------------+-----+
#|      valorant|    1|
#|counter-strike|    1|
#|          sims|    1|
#|          sims|    1|
#+--------------+-----+
```